# How to set up PYTHONPATH and project layout

Tags: python, pythonpath

So I've been working the last exercise of [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex52.html) and it states that before I run the program Ive been working on, you have to set the Pythonpath environment variable like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
```

I've done this, and after it wasn't working (Im assuming thats why when I try to run my program, I get an ImportError), I did some research on pythonpath. It's essentially says that Pythonpath is to find where to look for modules to import. So I set Pythonpath to the actual location of the module I'm trying to import and still to no avail.

Here's my directory:

```
- User/_myname_/python_stuff/projects/GothonWeb
    - bin/
        - __init__.py
        - app.py
    - gothonweb/
        - __init__.py
        - maps.py
    - templates (web.py)
        - game.html
        - index.html
        - layout.html
    - so forth and so on.
```

Im trying to run the app.py, which tries to import the main.py module:

```
from gothonweb import maps
```

But I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python_stuff/projects/GothonWeb/bin/app.py", line 2, in <module>
from gothonweb import maps
ImportError: No module named gothonweb
```

Anyone know whats up? Oh, some other details. Running on Python 2.7 on Mac Os X Lion, if that helps any.

Comment: Are you running from the folder ~/path/to/gothonweb/bin $ python app.py?

Comment: What is your pythonpath set to?

Comment: To answer Eswar, I run it like this: python pat/to/gothonweb/bin/app.py

And Bren, my pythonpath is set to: /Users/myname/python_stuff/projects/GothonWeb/gothonweb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the application like this:

```
$ cd ~/path/to/gothonweb/
python bin/app.py
```

However, if you did this:

```
$ cd bin/   # WRONG! WRONG! WRONG!
$ python app.py  # WRONG! WRONG! WRONG!
```

A lot of users tend to do this mistake, and [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html) is a nice explanation by Zed Shaw, on why not to run your app like this!

Then you are doing it wrong. In all python projects you do not cd into a lower directory to run things. You stay at the top and run everything from there so that all of the system can access all the modules and files.

Comment: After I typed in "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/myname/python_stuff/projects/GothonWeb/gothonweb", I entered it in just like you said and it worked. Why does it only work like that?

Comment: Yeah yeah! I saw it after I asked it. I guess I forgot that lesson. Thanks.

Comment: Does PYTHONPATH need to include ~/path/to/gothonweb/ for this solution to work?

Answer (score 3):

Alright to add to your python path in python, the easiest way to do it is at the TOP of your module.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(stringofpath)
```

You can recall that for each path you want to add.

`stringofpath` is the `/path/to/dir/` where `dir` is the directory your *project* sits in. *NOT* your project directory. Then use the normal dot notation starting from your project's directory to keep descending into all your sub directories.

In your case  your `stringofpath` is `'User/myname/python_stuff'`

As you advance you'll have to spend some serious time learning about your python path, there are a lot of things that are hard to find. And environment variables--in linux at least-- are permanently set in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell python where to load your package(i.e. the folder with `__init__.py` file).

To avoid mistakes mentioned above, you can set `PYTHONPATH` to the absolute path to your package folder, and then no matter what folder you are in, python would find your package.

Or you can use a virtual environment tool to help you manage these.